# Cannot read configured [PKCS12] keystore

Tags: java, elasticsearch, ssl, keystore, pkcs#12

```
[2023-12-15T11:56:28,285][ERROR][o.e.b.Elasticsearch      ] [node_1] fatal exception while booting Elasticsearchorg.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSecurityException: failed to load SSL configuration [xpack.security.transport.ssl] - cannot read configured [PKCS12] keystore [D:\Internship_task\elasticsearch\elasticsearch-8.9.0\config\elastic-certificates.p12] - this is usually caused by an incorrect password
        at org.elasticsearch.xcore@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.lambda$loadSslConfigurations$11(SSLService.java:617)
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1429)
        at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.forEach(Collections.java:1553)
        at org.elasticsearch.xcore@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.loadSslConfigurations(SSLService.java:613)
        at org.elasticsearch.xcore@8.9.0/org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.<init>(SSLService.java:159)

See logs for more details.

ERROR: Elasticsearch did not exit normally - check the logs at D:\Internship_task\elasticsearch\elasticsearch-8.9.0\logs\elasticsearch.log

ERROR: Elasticsearch exited unexpectedly
```

I am expecting to establish an elasticsearch connection in order to append the data for analysis. But I'm unable to establish to connection using ssl.

Below are the commands that have used to validate the password.

```
keytool -list -keystore "D:\Internship_task\elasticsearch\elasticsearch-8.9.0\config\elastic-certificates.p12"
bin/elasticsearch-keystore show xpack.security.http.ssl.keystore.secure_password
bin/elasticsearch-keystore show xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.secure_password
bin/elasticsearch-keystore show xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.secure_password
bin/elasticsearch-keystore list
```

below is my .yml file

```yaml
    xpack.security.http.ssl:
      enabled: true
      keystore.type: PKCS12
      keystore.path: D:\Internship_task\elasticsearch\elasticsearch-8.9.0\config\elastic-certificates.p12
    
    xpack.security.transport.ssl:
      enabled: true
      keystore.type: PKCS12
      keystore.path: D:\Internship_task\elasticsearch\elasticsearch-8.9.0\config\elastic-certificates.p12
      
      
    
      truststore.type: PKCS12
      truststore.path: D:\Internship_task\elasticsearch\elasticsearch-8.9.0\config\elastic-certificates.p12
```

Comment: "this is usually caused by an incorrect password", and you haven't provided a password.

Comment: Can you check the owner and permission of the path? `ls -ltrha D:\Internship_task\elasticsearch\elasticsearch-8.9.0\config\*`

Comment: @MusabDogan How will that cause a password problem?

Comment: Maybe because of the missing authentication, elastic can't read the file and can't read the password and can throw incorrect password. Anyway @dadonet answer is make sense to me, missing `xpack.security.ssl.keystore.secure_password`. Let's wait his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set `xpack.security.ssl.keystore.secure_password`?

It's a [secured setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/secure-settings.html).

If you did not, please read the complete guide at: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-basic-setup-https.html